# URL with www and non-www renders different screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, html, css, .htaccess

I have long appreciated this community for its robust technical solutions (Thank you!). But this is my first question so I hope I'm doing this correctly. (And, yes, I have searched for an answer to this question already.)

I am running into a weird problem (at least for me) regarding the same web page rendering into two different screen resolutions when a 'www' is used or when a 'non-www' is used. I assumed this had to do with some of my coding in my htaccess file but after commenting out any suspicious code, I'm not seeing any difference. In addition, whatever is happening upfront ends up hitting two different @media breakpoints in my CSS causing a slight difference in how the page displays. I have spent hours trying to resolve this so I'm now turning to the experts.

Here is an example of what I'm getting (note same page with and without 'www'):

https://www.clearviewperformance.com/resources/of/optimalfit.htm (renders at 2041 x 1218)
https://clearviewperformance.com/resources/of/optimalfit.htm (renders at 1837 x 1097)

My Chrome developer tools haven't provided any answers although I'm fairly new to using these tools and may be missing something.

Thank you for any direction you can provide.

Comment: They look the same to me, watch out for `rem` the use of `font-size: 0.7rem;` makes text too small to read on mobile

Comment: Did you change the browser zoom on one of the url which keeps saved and alter the `font-size` on one and not the other ?

Comment: search your css for `body {font-size: 95%;}`, your find some media querys which change the body text size,my comment above `rem` works from that, so if you have `body {font-size: 10px;}` like in one of them, the `font-size: 0.7rem;` will be too small

Comment: Thank you for your quick responses. First, if it were something in the CSS file wouldn't it affect the page rendering the exact same way regardless of whether a 'www' is used or not? I would think that if it had something to do with CSS it would have the same impact regardless.

Comment: I have two screen shots showing how Chrome Dev tools is seeing the files differently. How do I add images to this string?

Comment: Challet, thank you for your input. I have cleared my cache repeatedly to see if that made any difference. No difference. I don't as a rule change my browser zoom so I don't think that's it. Any other thoughts? Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I'm still hoping to get some insights from the community on the problem I've described. Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Thank you!